# Finding unused plugins in HUdson

Tags: hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

I am using Hudson 3.3.1 in my org and I see a bunch of unwanted plugins being added to the hudson. I am planning to get rid of those unwanted or unused plugin. I thought of scanning all the job config files, but I have following questions.

1. If there are plugins that not being used by hudson job configs, but used by hudson configuration, What\which files should I search for?
2. In configs what should I be searching for.  Pages what ever I am searching for is redirecting to jenkins pages.

I read through the following post [How to list all unused jenkins plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28542644/how-to-list-all-unused-jenkins-plugins)

I tried installing this plugin http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/plugin-usage-plugin/ , but it started throwing out error as I believe it is supported only by jenkins

Comment: Not sure why someone -1'd this, it seems like a reasonable question.

Answer (score 1):

I added an answer to the question you linked that adds steps on how to search the main Jenkins configuration file as well as individual job config files.  If you use the code in the linked question you should be able to find all the used plugins.